# Does php allocate memory when we new several objects of same class continuously but not assign any of them to variable?

Tags: php

Like the title described, let's see the code:

Here is an abstract base class :

```
 abstract class Unit
 {
    abstract function addUnit(Unit $unit);

    abstract function removeUnit(Unit $unit);

    abstract function bombardStrength();
 }
```

And two child classes :

```
class Army extends Unit
{
    private $units = array();

    function addUnit(Unit $unit)
    {
        var_dump($unit);
    }

    function removeUnit(Unit $unit){}
    function bombardStrength(){}
}

class Archer extends Unit
{
    function addUnit( Unit $unit ){}
    function removeUnit( Unit $unit ){}
    function bombardStrength(){}
}
```

client code :

```
$army = new Army();
$archer = new Archer();

$army->addUnit( $archer );
$army->addUnit( new Archer() );
$army->addUnit( new Archer() );
$army->addUnit( new Archer() );
$army->addUnit( new Archer() );
```

the result make me confused :

```
object(Archer)#2 (0) {
}
object(Archer)#3 (0) {
}
object(Archer)#3 (0) {
}
object(Archer)#3 (0) {
}
object(Archer)#3 (0) {
}
```

so, why are the last four objects the same ?

Comment: Because the same object resource id can be made available for reuse once its no longer being used; and those Archer objects are being discarded after the call to `addUnit()` because they aren't being used.... and memory is also being assigned, then made available again when the objects are discarded

Comment: thank you~so they share same resource id but are different objects, right ?

Comment: They're different objects, because you're creating them as different objects, and then discarding them again... so the same memory and resource id can be re-used